# Условие при Update атрибута MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 2 таблицы

```
CREATE TALBE table0(
id int,
atr0 varchar(max),
primary key(id));

CREATE TABLE table1(
id int,
atr0 varchar(max),
begin_date datetime,
end_date datetime);
```

Вторая таблица версионная - СКД2,атрибут `id` может содержать не уникальные значения. "Открытые" записи отличаются `end_date = 9999-12-31`.Возможны 2 ситуации: в `table1` есть 2 одинаковых `id` - первый с `end_date` = какое-то время, когда он перестал быть действительным, второй с `end_date = 9999-12-31`. Вторая ситуация, когда есть только один id c `end_date != 9999-12-31`. Необходимо выполнить

```
UPDATE table0
SET atr0 = table1.atr0
FROM table1
```

Если есть вторая запись("открытый" `id`) то проапдейтить `art0` c этой записи, а если нет, то `atr0 = null`. Вроде задача не сложная! В первом Update обновить все записи,

```
from (
select * 
from table1 
where not exists(select 1 
                 from stg.account_dda_version 
                 group by account_id 
                 having max(end_date)= '9999-12-31'
```

А во втором записи, `where end_date = '9999-12-31'`

Но в целях оптимизации запроса, жизненно необходимо запихать все эти действия в 1 `update`. Подскажите, как это можно сделать, если вообще возможно? СУБД MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вам нужно что-то подобное:

```
UPDATE t0 
    SET t0.eventdate = case when x.[max_eventdate] <> '9999-12-31' then x.[max_eventdate] else NULL end
FROM table0 t0
    JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(eventdate) [max_eventdate] FROM table1 t1 GROUP BY id) x on t0.id = x.id
```

Comment: да, примерно так, спасибо вам!